# Custom SVGElement labels loose positioning on zoom

Tags: highcharts

I create some custom SVGElement labels in my chart.. but they loose positioning on zooming the chart.. See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bz6vyedL/

```
chart:{zoomType: 'xy'},
```

Labels should not remain stuck when zooming in and behave appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reposition the label after every zoom, for example by using `render` event function:

```
chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy',
    events: {
        render: function() {
            var chart = this,
                point = chart.series[0].points[8],
                label = this.customLabel,
                xPos,
                labelWidth,
                newLabelPos;

            if (!label) {
                this.customLabel = label = chart.renderer.label(
                        'Label',
                        null,
                        null,
                        'callout',
                        null,
                        null,
                        true, false, 'my-label'
                    )
                    .attr({
                        padding: 0,
                        zIndex: 10
                    })
                    .add();
            }

            label.attr({
                x: point.plotX + chart.plotLeft,
                y: point.plotY + chart.plotTop
            });

            xPos = label.x;
            labelWidth = label.width;
            newLabelPos = xPos - labelWidth;

            label.attr('x', newLabelPos);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5v7xo2ky/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render